# React native callkeep incoming call expiration time

Tags: react-native, callkit

I'm using [callkeep](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-callkeep) to show an incoming call screen when a VoIP push notification is triggered. What I want to accomplish, is to ring the user for just 20 seconds. In case the user never answers, the incoming call screen should just disappear. How can I do that with callkeep?

Should it be modified in the javascript code or in the AppDelegate?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution, which is done on front end part.
First of all, run

`npm i react-native-background-timer`

This will help you run scheduled tasks when the app is closed.

Then, you will need to add the listener:

```
RNCallKeep.addEventListener("didDisplayIncomingCall", onIncomingCallDisplayed);
```

Which is fired when call is displayed.

And then implement it like this:

```
  const onIncomingCallDisplayed = ({callUUID, handle, fromPushKit, payload,}) => {
        BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {
            RNCallKeep.endAllCalls();
        }, 120000);
    };
```

Where 120000 is time in milliseconds when you want to end the call.
You could also add a backend request to notify your server that the call is rejected.

Comment: You must check if call connected first, `endAllCalls` with disable audio session while calling